# How to jump to source code of a method in Sublime Text with key binding?

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text editor, you can type COMMAND+P to search for other files based on file names
(fuzzy match greatly speeds up this process).

For example, if you see the following code in one source file (example in Ruby):

```
u = User.new
u.send_email
```

and you want to see the definition of User class, you can type COMMAND+P and enter "User" to see a list of candidate files (whose names contain "user") you can open to view.

Is it possible to jump to the source code of User class without typing "User"?

As you navigate in the source code, your cursor is on `User.new` or `u.send_email`,
it would be much faster if you can use some key-binding to jump to the file that contains the definition of either User class or the send_email method.

Is this supported by Sublime Text or any of its wonderful plugins?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A great way to do this is to install [`CTags`](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags).

Then you simply put your cursor over the class or method of interest:

[image]

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and it will jump to the location of that class or method's definition:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works well. How do you generate tags for only Ruby code, excluding, say, Javascript files?

Comment: There is an `exclude` flag you could set: [`−−exclude=[pattern]`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html).  That might work for your application.  It would be added to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/CTags/CTags.sublime-settings`

Comment: I know "ctags" support a --languages flag, but I can't seem to specify this with the sublime text ctags plugin user preference.  I'll try your suggestion.  But it would change the global behaviour for ctags. For me, I may want to vary this from project to project.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this answer. Having some C/C++ code-navigation in Sublime makes it Fantastic * 2. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

-Bookmarks: CTR + F2 to add, and F2 to go next bookmark

-Go to a method with CTRL +R in the active tab.

-'Jump to Symbol Definition' with a context menu with [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel).

-You can try with [Find Function Definition](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-find-function-definition), but it isn't entirely effective.