# Sublime Text 2: Is there anyway to automate the process of searching for a style in a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I tried to find something in a previous question but honestly I don't how to word the search query in order to get what I'm asking for, so I apologize if this has been answered in the past.

Is there any way that you can double click a class and that sublime takes you to the position of the stylesheet in which you can find that class.

I'm currently switching between the stylsheet tab and the html tab and I'm using ctrl+f to find the styles I want to edit but it seems a bit inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if [Ctags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) works with html/css, but you might look at an [answer I gave here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934456/how-to-jump-to-source-code-of-a-method-in-sublime-text-with-key-binding/21936882#21936882) and see if you can apply this to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4397

Something like that?

Quote from http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/96090-go-to-definitiondeclaration/:

> Currently, you can highlight function name, wherever in source code, and press ctrl+shift+f for searching across project files. And then you get file names and contexts where the function name appears.
>
> But this can be simplified, something like if the current search function is looking for something like: funciton_name = function or funciton function_name etc.. (for few cases how function desclaration can show up in php/js (for what I'm interested in) code.

Also, is it really that inefficient? How many times are you writing styles for any one particular class that means you can't find the one declaration you're looking for?

Comment: Great that was exactly what I was looking for! The reason I think is inefficient is because right now I'm editing the styles of a website that was not written by me, and since I'm going over it class by class it's kind of annoying. Maybe is just the cognitive load.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ah silly me, I hadn't considered it might not have been written by you. Fair enough then, hope this helps! :)